# Java to C# / Static Methods with non-typed Generic class parameters

Tags: java, c#, generics

I am converting a bunch of `Java` to `C#` via `Sharpen` and most of the conversion is fine and only needed minor tweaks but the generic conversion is fairly weak and needs a lot of clean up.

But in several areas, I am confused how downcasts (upcasts?) are being injected/compiled in Java since type parameters cannot be used in declarations of static methods.

**Given a Java `Graph` Generic class and one of it's subclass, `DependencyGraph<T>` :**

```
public class Graph<V, E>
{
   ~~~
}
public final class DependencyGraph<T> extends Graph<String, Object>
{
   ~~~
}
```

**The following Java static `Alorgithms.topo` gets calls with an array of different `Graph` and `Visitors` generics (and subclasses of those two base classes):**

```
public final class Algorithms
{
        public static void topoSort(Graph g, Visitor visitor)
        {
                Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[noOfDegreesOfFreedom];
                ~~~
        }
}
```

When a static method's parameter uses a generic class, i.e. `Graph g`, is the type passed to the static method handled by the Java's VM at runtime?

**Or** are the generic types realization inferred for each method calling `Alorgithms.topo` at compile time and folded into a single large class?

In the end of the day, I trying the figure out the least painful way to convert these to C#.

Comment: Java's generics are mostly syntactic sugar, so that makes things a bit different. I'm pretty sure the produced code knows nothing about the types so it can just go with not defining any types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, static methods in Java support generics as well. The method below can be declared in any class:

`public static <E> E[] appendToArray(E[] array, E item)`

Regarding your last question, generics are only used at compile time to prevent potential cast exceptions at runtime. This is the [Type Erasure mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

If you do not specify any type for your generic (eg `Graph`), Java will just assume it is a `Graph<Object>`.